# Automatically takes a space after 4 letters in text input field in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

If i entered text in text-input field then automatically it takes a space after 4 digits.

Here is my code for text-input field:

```
handleCardNumber = (text) => {
    this.setState({ cardNumber: text })
}

<TextInput
    ref="first"
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    style={styles.cardNumberTextInput}
    placeholder="1234 1234 1234 1234"
    placeholderTextColor="grey"
    returnKeyType='next'
    keyboardType = {'numeric'}
    onChangeText={this.handleCardNumber}
    onSubmitEditing={(event)=>{
    this.refs.second.focus();
}}
```

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your code with below:

```
handleCardNumber = (text) => {
  let formattedText = text.split(' ').join('');
  if (formattedText.length > 0) {
    formattedText = formattedText.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join(' ');
  }
  this.setState({ cardNumber: formattedText });
  return formattedText;
}
```

Add this line in your input code to show changes state value:

```
value={this.state.cardNumber}
```

JS Demo: (enter more than 4 digits)

```js
handleCardNumber = (text) => {
      let formattedText = text.split(' ').join('');
      if (formattedText.length > 0) {
        formattedText = formattedText.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join(' ');
      }
      //this.setState({ cardNumber: text });
      console.log(formattedText)
      return formattedText;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" onchange="handleCardNumber(this.value)" >
```

Comment: What exactly is not working, I have also added the js demo for the same

Comment: of course, the first portion of answer is to replace your code of React Native. and to demonstrate the logic I have created js snippet as  React Native is js framework :)

Comment: you need to set the state with updated text like `this.setState({ cardNumber: formattedText });` and display using  `value={this.state.cardNumber}` . I also tested code on expo it is working. If not for you then update your full code so we can help you

Comment: Glad to help you :)